# Loading Different Database for Different User - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel project(main) and i am loading another laravel project(secondary) using iframe in a module of my main project.
Now what i need to do is load different database for secondary project by different user of main project.
It would be great if anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have done this! I had to create a middleware and add this middleware in route middlewaregroup.

```
class ChangeDatabase
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $database_name = Auth::user()->database;
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            Config::set('database.connections.tenant', array(
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      =>  '',
                'database'  => $database_name,
                'username'  => 'forge',
                'password'  => '',
                'port'  => '3306',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            ));
            Config::set('database.default', 'tenant');
            $user = User::where('id', $user_id)->first();
            Auth::guard()->login($user);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then i had to create a trait and used to in all model.

```
trait DatabaseChangerTrait {
    public function __construct(){

        if (Auth::check()) {
            $database_name = Auth::user()->database;

            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            Config::set('database.connections.tenant', array(
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      =>  '',
                'database'  => $database_name,
                'username'  => 'forge',
                'password'  => '',
                'port'  => '3306',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            ));
            Config::set('database.default', 'tenant');
            $user = User::where('id', $user_id)->first();
            Auth::guard()->login($user);
        }
    }
}
```